# Unable to install wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, unzip

i've downloaded a wordpress theme(clubber) but when i try to install it on my wordpress 3.9, it shows the error message while unzipping which is

The package could not be installed. PCLZIP_ERR_BAD_FORMAT (-10) : Unable to find End of Central Dir Record signature

i have no idea whats the problem. please help

Comment: instead of installing it through wordpress, just add it to the themes directory and see what happens then

Comment: @Andrew Matthew thanks. I've done that(it's working) but the theme is not looking what it should as in the preview. what should i do now..?

Comment: Well you'll now have to costumize your theme to look as you wish. By adding/removing widgets etc. the way how it looks like, it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

That has often been my expression of late as a result of my frequent WordPress troubleshooting.
Due to my busy schedule, I haven’t had time to login to my blog. On one of my spare time, I took it as an opportunity to update my plugins, as usual with WP automatic update via my dashboard. One of such plugins that desperately needed an update was WpOptimix, a premium WordPress security plugin. While the update was going on, suddenly it came to a halt and below is the error message I got

An error occurred while updating wpOptimix: The package could not be installed. PCLZIP_ERR_BAD_FORMAT (-10) : Unable to find End of Central Dir Record signature

I knew this has to be a server configuration, since I have got no time to spare, rather than spending countless number of hours troubleshooting this error, I decided to take the shortest way out – deactivated and deleted the problematic plugin, re-downloaded, uploaded and activated the updated plugin Archive file (.zip) via WordPress plugin dashboard (http://yoursite.com/wp-admin/plugin-install.php?tab=upload).

A known solution to this problem is simply commenting out mbstring.func_overload php.ini directive (subject to your host granting you access to php.ini) as signified below

;mbstring.func_overload=7

Answer (score 0):

You must unzip the downloaded theme zip file after then you should open unzipped folder and see another zip file overthere. that zip file you have to upload on WordPress > Add New theme page. I'm sure you'll not get that error again on your computer screen.